# How do I edit/update records from a database using textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, linq-to-sql

I have a problem and I would like your help. I have in my page an edit button and textboxes. I want to edit one single record from the database to these textboxes. I wrote the following code, when I click the edit button then I have the results. The results load in my textboxes. But when I try again to run the page with the same ID for second time then I have this error 'Specified cast is not valid.'  What's going wrong? I used int ID=3; to get the 3rd record in this example

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

DataClassesDataContext cxt = new DataClassesDataContext();
                USER_TABLE aChar = cxt.USER_TABLEs.Single(c => c.ID == 3);   //gets a single record

```
            fname2.Text = aChar.FIRST_NAME;
            lname2.Text = aChar.LAST_NAME;
            pob2.Text = aChar.PLACE_OF_BIRTH;
            pom2.Text = aChar.PLACE_OF_MARRIAGE;
            education2.Text = aChar.EDUCATION;
            occupation2.Text = aChar.OCCUPATION;
            pod2.Text = aChar.PLACE_OF_DEATH;
            String str = aChar.DATE_OF_BIRTH.ToString();
           String str1 = aChar.DATE_OF_MARRIAGE.ToString();
            String str2 = aChar.DATE_OF_DEATH.ToString();
```

Comment: Your question has nothing related to LINQ.  I'll edit your question.

Comment: Stephen - he's using Linq-to-sql - so maybe remove sql and linq and put linq-to-sql in?

Comment: You do have one LINQ call (.Single), but it is obviously not causing the problem because your site is not failing on an exception (if that LINQ call failed, Single will throw an exception) -- otherwise you will see an error output, not the same page.

Comment: Which row gives you the error now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you doing `if (!Page.IsPostBack)` in your event handler code?

I'd say that normally an event is only raised upon post-back...

I rarely see IsPostBack used in anything other than PageLoad.

Comment: ok!I deleted the if (!Page.IsPostBack). Again I have the same page without results. Without anything! The problem is in the ID I thing. For a reason this code cannot get it.

Comment: First, you should amend your question.  Second, you set ID=3, then immediately overwrite it with the ID passed into the Request.  If the ID parameter passed together with your URL is not a valid number, then TryParse will fail and you'll get nothing.

Comment: Thanks Stephen for your comment!So what do you think can I change to get the record with the 3rd ID?

Comment: strID = "3" before the TryParse call.  This will make sure that TryParse succeeds and it will parse to 3.

Comment: really not sure this is the right answer to mark as "accepted"? While it's helpful... I don't think it solves the actual problem? e.g. I don't think it would help someone else looking for an answer to the same problem. Or have I totally misunderstood something?

Comment: I think @user576998's problem came from having strID in an invalid format that does not parse, so TryParse fails and drops off the if-block.  Agree that this probably has little to do with his original question though -- I can identify quite a few time-bombs in this code that will translate quickly to bugs later on.

Comment: We can definitely agree there are a few problems in here - but I suspect the main problem was the lack of SubmitChanges() - what's strange is that userX marked both answers as accepted... guess we'll have to wait and see what she/he says...

Comment: I found the solution!!!I edit my question again with my new code. But I have one other question as you can see

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly save your changes to the context

```
cxt.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: You mean I must add this context to my code?Because I have this context in my UPDATE button

Comment: add it as the last line - if you don't call it, then you won't update the database. see example in http://www.richardbushnell.net/2008/02/18/how-to-update-data-with-linq-to-sql/ - get the data, update the data, submit the changes

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are getting a specified cast exception when fetching your object (using Single). You may want to check the data types between your object model and the database to make sure the object isn't expecting numbers where the database uses strings (or vice versa). Also, check the nullability of your objects and database columns. LINQ to SQL does not support implicit type conversions when binding.

As for why it is working on the first request, but not the second, what has changed between the requests? Also, is the context kept alive between the two requests? Single caches the fetched value and short circuits the query pipeline when the same ID is requested a second time, so with Single you should only see one database request if the context was kept alive. Try using ctx.Log = Console.Out to log your database requests, or SQL Profiler if you have it.